# Scala: Append to Array within a Map

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, immutability

I am learning immutable types in Scala and am struggling to get this elementary task done. I simply need to append to an array of doubles that is within a map. I do not want to use ArrayBuffer.

My ultimate goal is to make an adjacency matrix. When I append a new item to the map (an (Int, double) tuple) I want to increase the size of each array within the map--essentially increasing the dimension of the matrix.

```
var map = Map[Int, Array[Double]]()
map += (0 -> new Array[Double](5))

// HOW TO DO THIS
map(0) = map(0) :+ 0.01

for ((i, a) <- map) {
    print(i + ": ")
    for (d <- a) print(d + ", ")
}
```

What I have written above does not compile. However `map(0) :+ 0.01` alone will but it does not achieve my goal of appending to an immutable array within a map.

Comment: can you please clarify the question a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is immutable Map, you can't change the value in place, as you've tried to do using `map(0) = map(0) :+ 0.01`.
The one of the possible solutions is using `updated` method, which returns updated map (all methods like *add*, *remove*, *modify* in immutable data structures return new data struture):

```
map = map.updated(0, map(0) :+ 0.01)
```

Some examples to prove:

```
var map = Map[Int, Array[Double]]()
map += (0 -> new Array[Double](5))
map = map.updated(0, map(0) :+ 0.01)
map(0) // res1: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01)
map = map.updated(0, map(0) :+ 0.02)
map(0) // res2: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.02)
```

Comment: It can't. I'll give some examples soon

Comment: Okay sorry to give you the run around but I can confirm that your solution does work and does not drop entries in the map. Thanks for your help.